# Azure Batch integration with Bitbucket

Tags: azure, bitbucket, azure-batch

Is there any way to build and deploy Azure Batch Application Packages when changes are pushed to Bitbacket repository?

I'm looking for the same Deployment approach as for Azure Functions or something like this.

Comment: Hey, Cool idea, but whole scenario is not clear. You probably want to add more detail in your scenario and how you are presumably doing this. Please note primarily Batch is not a deploying tool, but if you are crafting / Architecture-ing a solution around it, then it will help to detail in greater detail. `:)` that might help to understand idea clearly and give you more detail reply. Thanks.

Comment: The idea is that I want to update Application Package on Bitbucket trigger. 
I have a recurring job which runs application from Application Package every minute. This application is under development, so I want to update application each time I push changes to master branch on my Bitbucket repository.
Azure Functions have Deployment Options where I can integrate with my Bitbucket repository

Comment: Cool, based on what you just said, I think I have shared some idea below, just something on top of my head. hope it helps `:)`

Answer (score 1):

To start with this is what I think on top of my head.

Cool, I will share some information and thoughts around this, I am sure you can make use of the information to help your idea.

There are 2 levels of application package:

- Pool level; and
- Task level

Detail information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages

The pool level is set at the pool level and available to any task joining the pool where as the task level gets unpacked at the creation of task.

*Please be aware of* the max limits of pkgs etc:
* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-quota-limit#other-limits

**Key**

AFAIK, there is **no flag** which can tell the vm that the current pkg is updated, hence in your scenario 2 things can happen:

- pool level Scenario: if you are joining the pool every time: If you can afford to create pool i.e. at the join pool level then you can keep the package name and every time the code is updated you can recreate the pool which will end up creating the whole thing again  i.e. the new package will get picked up.
- Task level: If you don't want to create pool all the time, then you can do it by creating new task every time your code gets changed, not the caveat to that will be the **max** limit which is described at the link above.

Both ways you can do it via **user code** but deciding between what scenario will suite you depends on the grand architecture of the case.

**Information flow possibility at user end**

- some resource in bit bucket.
- User at any change in that resource ==> packs it in *.zip format and then carry on with the batch side of things.
- User create the pool or mention task level packages (depending on the detail above); can also add the versions for the same package (beaware of the max limits here)
- pkg is available in vm.

**Alternate approach:**

- There is another way this can be done which is non package way:
- Mount drive to the node at start task:

  - And user code has to make user that drive always gets updated will latest version of “*.files”

I hope this help your scenario \ design `:)`, thanks!